# LocalCache guava, optimization for higher throughput

Tags: java, performance, caching, guava

I'm using CacheBuilder and LocalCache from guava library, but have some performance issues p99.9 latency around 300-400 ms for getAllPresent.
Latency for requests almost doubles between p99 and p99.9 (p99 is around 150 ms)

The following configuration is used:
120 sec for refreshAfterWrite, maxsize is set to be 2e6 and expiration for 24 hours, initial capacity is 1e6. No removeListener is used and no expireAfterWrite. ConcurrencyLevel 256 (Tried different values). Machine has 12 cores.
While cache is in use it has between 8e5 to 1.2e6 entries.
Pattern of usage is getAllPresent for around 3k keys on p99.9 and around 100 qps.

Key is a complex object for hashCode, Objects.hash method is used with all fields supplied there. I tried different hash function to make sure that distribution is uniform (murmur3 shown similar results). So, the problem is not in collisions.

Any pointers on how to tune it to be more performant?

Comment: Care to share your actual benchmark code?

Comment: Not much to share, simply put stopwatch.start(); before cache.getAllPresent and stopwatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) after. There is separate system to track stats from machines where this latency is reported. Later it get's aggregated from all machines.

Comment: Do you mean refreshAfterWrite? Are you using a CacheLoader? getAllPresent() would not invoke the cache loader.

Comment: Yes, refreshAfterWrite. Yes, I'm using cacheLoader override reload only. getAllPresent() may trigger scheduleRefresh

Answer (score 3):

I would say it is efficient in Java for the 99%tile to be double the 90%tile and for the 99.9%tile to be double the 99%tile.  If you see this pattern, you will need to reduce the cost of the operation over all to reduce the latency i.e. it is unlikely there is some quick wins that will help you.

NOTE: when you have a large cache and scan across it you can expect every entry to involve at least one or two L3 cache misses.  This is going to be expensive.  For a small cache which fits in your CPU cache this will be many times faster.

I would use a profiler to reduce CPU and memory allocation for this operation, or change the how you call the cache to do what you need and this will also bring down the 99.9%tile.

Comment: Peter, can you elaborate on this:  If you see this pattern, you will need to reduce the cost of the operation over all?

Comment: The pattern I describe is normal for efficient and non-trivial code IMHO and to me indicates there isn't going to be some quick wins. To improve the result you have to make the typical performance faster and this will improve all the percentiles.  A profile is good at helping you improve the typical or average latencies (but not so good at finding problems in the high percentiles specifically).

Comment: @RomanDzhabarov See this presentation esp slide 8 http://www.slideshare.net/PeterLawrey/writing-and-testing-high-frequency-trading-engines-in-java

Comment: to the first your comment. The percentile I'm talking about is specifically for the getAllPresent call it only considers the diff after getAllPreset executed and before, but I do agree that GC for example might have impact on it and problem not specifically in guava cache itself. I still want to make sure params are chosen optimally. For example, if i extend refresh to 10 mins I get significantly better  numbers... but in reality 10 mins is to long for that

Comment: @RomanDzhabarov The percentile ratios I quote is for a gc-free application/code.  If you have GCs, you can expect far worse percentiles. i.e. ratios of 10-20x I suggest you profile your application to see what is spending most of the time doing.

Comment: Yourkit does not show that this cache has any problems, it shows different hot spots, I guess it's not good for finding problems which appears in worst case.

Comment: @RomanDzhabarov it isn't but you need to improve the performance of your caching code in general to reduce the high percentiles, it's just telling you have far worse problems than worrying about your cache.  You can have yourkit focus just on the code of interest. (either using their library to turn on profiling for your section of code or by narrowing your results)

Comment: Well, all the places which are marked as hotspots on average has bigger latency that this cache (this cache average latency is OK), but p99 for instance or p99.9 for this cache is far worse than the rest of the places which means if I want to have my service have success rate 99.5 for example from upstream with the latency budget of 380ms and this cache on p99 gives 400ms I'm off my latency budget requirements and cannot guarantee the above success rate.

Comment: @RomanDzhabarov BTW my 99%tile latency budget is usually 100 micro-seconds.  I understand the problem, but you have to find a way to make this operation less expensive all the time and the 99.9%tile will come down.

Comment: @Peter: Besides the GC, lock contention may also be an issue if the requested key space does overlap. See my answer on this.

Answer (score 3):

**On varying request times / "Request times doubles between p99 and p99.9"**

That might simply be an occasional GC during the getAllPresent call. To really investigate this you should do a stripped down benchmark which tracks the GC activity (just the counters).

Another source of trouble may be a lock contention. I am missing in your problem statement the exact access pattern. How many requests are done in parallel? How does the key space overlap? Guava partitions the cache hashtables internally and uses the concurrencyLevel as hint. The read access is not completely lock free, since the LRU list needs to be updated. For accessing the same key from different threads, this is a source for lock contention. Here is an (outdated) evaluation on [nitro cache performance](http://sourceforge.net/p/nitrocache/wiki/Performance/) showing this effect. (Update: the guava cache has some strategy to avoid the locks on read; this needs further investigation)

**On how to get (15 times?) faster**

The most costly thing when you access the cache is the eviction algorithm updating its data structure. However, your maximum cache size (2E6) is above the maximum experienced size (1.2E6). This means no eviction will take place, because the capacity limit is never reached. This means that all the updating of the LRU list in Guava Cache is senseless. I have benchmarked the cache runtime for Google Guava, EHCache, infinispan and different eviction strategies at [cache2k benchmarks](http://cache2k.org/benchmarks.html) see the "runtime comparison for hits". Benchmarks for multi threaded accesses are missing yet, this will show up during august.

From my understanding there is no option to change or switch of the eviction strategy in Guava Cache (can anybody second this?).

Within cache2k I do experiment with alternative eviction strategies which allow a lock free read access. Within your scenario, you could simply select "random eviction", and I would expect a speedup of about factor 15. BTW: The cache2k cache also prints out hash table statistics and a quality metric for your hashCode() implementation see the notes on [cache2k statistics](https://github.com/headissue/cache2k/blob/master/src/site/markdown/statistics.md).

It should be possible to do a quick evaluation. Here some code snippets to get you started quickly:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.cache2k</groupId>
  <artifactId>cache2k-core</artifactId>
  <version>0.19.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.cache2k</groupId>
  <artifactId>cache2k-api</artifactId>
  <version>0.19.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Remark: The cache implementations are not exposed in the API module, that's why we need the core module in the compile scope. Cache initialization:

```
// optional data source (similar to CacheLoader)
CacheSource<Integer, String> source =
  new CacheSource<Integer, String>() {
    public String get(Integer o) {
      return o + "hello";
    }
  };
Cache<Integer, String> cache =
  CacheBuilder.newCache(Integer.class, String.class)
    .implementation(RandomCache.class)
    .maxSize(3000000)
    .expiryMillis(120 * 1000)
    /* optional, if cache should do the refresh itself
    .source(source)
    .backgroundRefresh(true)
    */
  .build();
```

You can experiment with other eviction algorithms by altering the `implementation` option.
`getAllPresent` is not available in cache2k, you can code it yourself:

```
public Map<Integer, String> getAllPresent(Iterator<Integer> it) {
  HashMap<Integer, String> hash = new HashMap<>();
  while(it.hasNext()) {
    int k = it.next();
    String v = cache.peek(k);
    if (v != null) {
      hash.put(k, v);
    }
  }
  return hash;
}
```

In cache2k `cache.peek()` returns a mapped element without invoking the cache source, that is exactly the intended semantic of `getAllPresent`. Building up the hash map produces actually a lot GC load. The usage of bulk operations like `getAll` or `getAllPresent` should be a careful decision. Since the access times in cache2k are similar to a hash table access time, bulk operations will probably not speed things up.

**A note on getAllPresent()**

Within cache2k there is a JSR107 compatible `getAll()` method which serves about the same purpose. From an API designers standpoint these methods are evil, since it contradicts the idea of the cache to control the resources. Just got with cache.get() or cache.peek(). If there is a CacheSource (aka CacheLoader) use `cache.prefetch(keys)` "say to the cache" that you want to work with these keys next.... Sorry, a little offtopic.

Comment: no eviction will take place, but what about refresh time? which causes key to be reload?

Comment: access pattern is multiget on 100-3k keys

Comment: "What about refresh time?" For the timer the cache uses another data structure. For the refreshing/expiry to happen the cache needs to update its data when a cache entry is **updated**. For a "good eviction" to happen, the cache needs to update a data structure on every **read access**. That is a big difference.

Comment: @cruftex, is the statement `The read access is not lock free` in your answer correct in all cases? My question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24755464/948268 shows contrary outcome. What's your thought on this? In my case I have `concurrencyLevel(1)`.

Comment: @KuldeepJain, you are right, my statement seems only "partially" correct. I need to dig deeper into Guava!