# Is Guava Cache's read lock free

Tags: java, caching, guava

I am using Guava's Cache and have set `concurrencyLevel` to `1` so the maximum capacity is utilized w.r.t. eviction is concerned. Following is my code:

```
CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                    .maximumWeight(maxWeight)
                    .concurrencyLevel(1)
                    .expireAfterWrite(expireDuration, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .removalListener(new RemovalListener<K, V>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onRemoval(RemovalNotification<K, V> removalNotification) {
                            log.warn(removalMsg + removalNotification.getKey());
                        }
                    })
                    .weigher(weigher)
                    .build();
```

Documentation of [concurrencyLevel](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#concurrencyLevel%28int%29) says this:

> Guides the allowed concurrency among update operations. Used as a hint
>   for internal sizing. The table is internally partitioned to try to
>   permit the indicated number of concurrent updates without
>   contention...

And hence I was assuming that the `concurrencyLevel` plays a role only for `update operations` and the `READs are Lock Free` even with `concurrencyLevel(1)`.

Is my assumption correct ??

---

**EDIT:**
I looked at the Guava Caching codeand it looks like my assumption that `READs are lock free` is correct. In case of `get(K, Callable)` initially it tries to get the value without lock and if the entry for the specified key is either null or has expired only then it goes for a locked Get or Load. Please Correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: How can they possibly be lock-free if you are using only one partition instead of multiples? The whole point of partitioning is to not increase contention on different parts of the cache.

Comment: But then why does the documentation specifically says `allowed concurrency among update operations` and no mention about the read operation. I had thought that similar to `ConcurrentHashMap` here as well the reads would generally be lock free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look at the code yourself. Most of the relevant stuff is in [`LocalCache`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/cache/LocalCache.java).

Anyway, from my understanding (I'm not an expert on the cache stuff), reads (on a non-`LoadingCache`) should generally be lock-free (on a `LoadingCache` it depends on whether they need to load a value, in which case the read becomes a write too). In some code paths `tryLock()` is used to acquire a lock, but since it's `tryLock()` no reading threads should block if the lock is held I don't think.

**Edit:**

From comments in `Segment`:

> Segments maintain a table of entry lists that are ALWAYS kept in a consistent state, so can be read without locking.

(`concurrencyLevel(1)` currently means 1 `Segment`.)

Comment: the comments in the Segment class claim that the reads are lock free.

Comment: @jtahlborn: Oh yeah, so they do!

Comment: +1 Thanks ColinD, yeah I looked at the code & also updated question with my observation.

Comment: @KuldeepJain: Yes, in the case of `get(K, Callable)` there's a potential write involved if there isn't a value already present for the key.